# cargar una tabla sin refrescar pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas como puedo actualizar mi tabla, antes solo mandaba mi funcion cunado insertaba un registro y solo la recargaba  pero cambie de dataTable y ya no lo hace tengo q recargar la pagina, le puse un console.log y si entra pero no actualiza
Cambie mis librerias a estas y ya no me funciono como antes

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

mi funcion

```
function cargar_requerido(data)//FUNCION CARGAR DATOS EN LA TABLA
{

    var html = '';
    $('#body_').empty();
    var transcurrido = 0;


var dt = new Date();//TOMAR LA FECHA
var month = dt.getMonth()+1;
var day = dt.getDate();
var year = dt.getFullYear();
var fecha = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
     var diffTime = moment(fecha).diff(data[i].fecha_registro);//CUENTA LOS DIAS TRANSCURRIDOS DEL DIA DE REGISTRO HASTA LA ACTUAL
            var dias = diffTime/86400000;//DIVIDE EL RESULTADO DE MILISEGUNDOS PARA PASARLOS A DIAS
            console.log(dias);


         var boton = (data[i].ase== '' || data[i].ase == null) ? '<div data-id="'+data[i].id+'" data-nombre= "'+data[i].contacto+'" class="btn btn-primary registrar">Asignar</div>' : data[i].ase;

         html+= '<tr><td class="center">'+data[i].fecha+
            '</td><td class="center">'+dias+
            '</td><td class="center">'+data[i].contacto+
            '</td><td class="center" data-id="'+data[i].id+'">'+boton+ 
            '</td></tr>';
    }
    $('#body').html(html);

  var table = $('#table').DataTable();

  table.destroy();

    $('#table').DataTable( {

           dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ]
    } );
    $('.dataTables_filter input').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("placeholder", "Buscar");
        });


}
```

Comment: Te hace falta importar el script de Datatable

Comment: esas son mis librerias